# Form doesn't show anything

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I am new to Winforms and C# so this may sound like a stupid question. I have the class shown below for creating a form to be displayed as a modal dialog.

```
class FrmDelivery : Form
{
    ListBox s;
    public FrmDelivery()
    {
        s = new ListBox();

        s.DataSource = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};
        s.Update();
        s.Show();

    }

}
```

However for some reson when I use the `ShowDialog`method to display this form it doesnt show anything in it. What should I do to add a list box to this form ?

***EDIT:***

I use the code to display the form:

```
       FrmDelivery frm = new FrmDelivery();
        frm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: You are trying to show the listbox rather than the form.

Comment: please see my edit @ChrisF I think its realted to what you said

Comment: You still have `s.Show();` in your `FrmDelivery` constructor. That's wrong. You're also not adding the list box to the visual tree. If you explained why you can't use XAML for this it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a new form using Add|New Item|Windows Form.
You will then get a design surface to which you can add a listbox, and generated code which will initialize your form and listbox correctly.  In particular your form and listbox will gain default sizes which they don't have currently.

Your code (in say Form1.cs) will then be similar to this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.listBox1.DataSource = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }

    public int? SelectedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (int?)this.listBox1.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Plus there will be a load of code in Form1.Designer.cs similar to

```
....

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listBox1
        // 
        this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 37);
        this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 95);
        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
```

And you could use your form like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var form = new Form1()) // you should dispose forms used as dialogs
        {
            if (DialogResult.OK == form.ShowDialog()) // optional (you could have OK/Cancel buttons etc
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(form.SelectedValue ?? -1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking: How do I make it so that when user selects a value from the list box, I can obtain the value from where the `ShowDialog` method was called ?

Comment: You should probably ask another question - but I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One note - WPF uses Windows, not Forms, so I'm not clear why you're deriving from Form rather than `Window`.  But I'll answer as if you were talking about a WPF Window as your "form".

First, something will need to display the Window.  Currently, the code provided doesn't show the Window, it attempts to show a `ListBox`.

Second, you either need to add a LayoutPanel to the window and add your `ListBox` as a child of the layout panel.  Layout Panels come in many flavors, such as `Grids` and `StackPanels` and `Canvases` based on what type of layout you want.

Or, you can set the `Content` of the `Window` to be your `ListBox`.  This will mean the only thing on the `Window` is your `ListBox', so if you want multiple visual elements on your`Window`, you'll need to use a layout panel.

The second approach would look like

```
this.Content = s;
```

For the first approach, I'd recommend reading up on Layout Panels in WPF.  [Here is one tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx) is the MSDN topic on layout.  A google search will yield many more results.

Comment: Sorry I meant WinForms my bad.. I dont't think it has a content property

Comment: +1 for the answer - even though it no longer applies, it answered the original well.

Comment: The question is about WinForms not WPF

Comment: @Phil, originally he had it tagged as WPF, hence the confusion.

Comment: You're welcome - I thought if nobody mentions this you'll get downvotes at a later time ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the listbox to the controls collection:

```
ListBox s;
public FrmDelivery()
{
  s = new ListBox();
  s.DataSource = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

  this.Controls.Add(s);
}
```

This will get the control onto your form for you, though there are a bunch of other properties you will likely want to set (e.g. to get it looking how you want) - as others have mentioned, you can see how the designer does this in the code behind by putting a listbox onto a form and examining the resulting code.

Answer (score 1):

You should not only add the controls to the collection but also set up his caracteristics.
Size & emplacement, at least.

```
class FrmDelivery : Form
{
ListBox s;
public FrmDelivery()
{
    s = new ListBox();
    s.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0); //relative to the parent control (not an absolute value, so)
    s.Name = "listBox1";
    s.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 95);


    s.DataSource = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};
    this.Controls.Add(s); //it will add it to the form but you can add it to another control, like panel.

}
```

}

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you have the InitializeComponent() in the default construct commented out. It usually initializes all the control of the form on FormLoad.